# Android MediaPlayer seekTo operation causes ANR

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

When I do mediaPlayer.seekto operation sometimes it causes anr.I am currently playing the video from a web server.Anyway I can cancel a seek operation.

Comment: you can implement MediaController.MediaPlayerControl and override all its methods which seekTo is one of them

Comment: I am using custom controllers not media controller.There are buttons for forward and backward seek.